# Increment nth-child Selector of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With refernece to [That](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

I need to iterate through nth-child selector, That is

```
var i =1;    
var tmp = $(this).find('td:nth-child(i+1)'); // Wondering How this behavior can be achieved     
i++;
```

What i have is a row/rows with dynamically generated columns in a grid, i want to loop through  each grid cell and Store value of each grid cell with header i.e its ID.
i was wondering if i could increment selector in nth-child so .each for every iteration it catches the next gridcell value. And so I can push its value and Id to array for further use.

Any sort of help would be appreciative.

Regards

Comment: Uhm. Why not use `.each` to iterate over the elements? `$(this).find('td').each(...)` http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: `$(this).find('td:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')');` - `i` is a variable...

Comment: It gets me whole row for each specific ID

Comment: I don't know which ID you are talking about. Do you mean you only want to get the first `td` element of each row? It's really difficult to understand what you are actually trying to do. Please post your HTML and the result you want to get. Using the `nth-child` selector in this situation is most likely wrong.

Comment: Please have a look
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680837/grid-selecting-header-id-from-one-and-content-values-from-another-table-and-pus

Comment: Is this the same question? If so, please don't ask questions twice. Anyways, if you only want to get the first `td` element, use `$(this).find('td').first()` or `$(this).find('tr td:first-child')`, depending on what `this` is and which values you actually want. I still don't completely understand the problem.

Comment: The thing i am trying another approach, so thats why i go for another question.
Both questions are distant apart because of the methodology I am following .. 
PS I do not want forst but all elemrnt values in grid row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a variable like `'td:nth-child(i+1)'`.

Change it to:

`var tmp = $(this).find('td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')');`