# How to get the first 10-row, the last 3-row and 2-row in the center with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a new with Javascript so that please tell me:

1)How to get the first 10-row, the last 3-row and 2-row in the center with

**`var firstTable = $('#aaa table').eq(0);`**

2)How to create and set a new "id" & "class" attributes for the

`<table>` (line 2) like `<table id="newid" class="newclass">`

(jQuery might go with this section)?

```
<div id="aaa">
    <table>
        <tr>1</tr>
        <tr>2</tr>
        <tr>3</tr>
        <tr>4</tr>
        <tr>5</tr>
        <tr>6</tr>
        <tr>7</tr>
        <tr>8</tr>
        <tr>9</tr>
        <tr>10</tr>
        <tr>11</tr>
        <tr>12</tr>
        <tr>13</tr>
        <tr>14</tr>
        <tr>15</tr>
        <tr>16</tr>
        <tr>17</tr>
        <tr>18</tr>
        <tr>19</tr>
        <tr>20</tr>
    </table>
    <table id="bbb">
        something goes here
    </table>
```

The output for question 1 could be:
The first 10-row:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

The last 3-row:

18
19
20

The 2-row in the center: This must be from the last row of the first 10-row

10
11

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: $('#aaa table').eq(0).attr( "id", "newid" ).attr("class","newclass");  for class ,ans id to set

Comment: the first 10-row: 1 -> 10, the last 3-row: 18 -> 20 and the 2 rows in the center: 10 -> 11 from the last row of 10 so it cannot be 9 -> 10.

Comment: I am not clear about the first question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the question 2. Yet I still got problem with question 1 that how to catch the last row of the first 10-row

Comment: Use    tr:nth-child(Here will be variable from 1 to 10)

Comment: by mistake i put solution in comment

Comment: check this question [jQuery :nth-child() selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026885/jquery-nth-child-selector) and [Increment nth-child Selector of Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697726/increment-nth-child-selector-of-jquery)

Comment: **@Pratik Joshi**: What should I do with firstTable in order to get the first 10-row, the last 3-row and 2-row in the center?

Comment: **@Eugine Joseph**: Thank you for your response. `firstTable.find('table tr').first()` with this, I can get the first row but how can I get the first 10-row with Javascript? I prefer to use Javascript than jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1st question

```
$('#aaa table').eq(0).attr( "id", "newid" ).attr("class","newclass"); for class ,ans id to set
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T97jm/5/

For last 3 records

http://jsfiddle.net/T97jm/6/

for inner 2 elements

http://jsfiddle.net/T97jm/7/

for your table =>tr

http://jsfiddle.net/T97jm/8/

Comment: Thank you very much please let me know how to use `firstTable` to get the first 10-row, the last 3-row and 2-row in the center?

Comment: posted fiddle for getting fist 10

Comment: **@Pratik Joshi**: That is nice with Javascript. Thank you again. How about the last 3-row and 2-row in the center?

Comment: **@Pratik Joshi**: Great! and the 2-row in the center? the output goes with 10, 11, not with 9, 10, because it is **the last row** (10) from the first 10-row.

Comment: wait till i do with LUNCH,c u later

Comment: **@Pratik Joshi**: That's fine. I am still waiting. Have a nice lunch! :-)

Comment: well if you got the answer consider choosing answer as best answer

Comment: **@Pratik Joshi**: I voted for the best answer :-) I really desire to send reputation but it requires 15 reputation... Anyway I am still exploiting lots of features here.